# Using if with loop

Tags: perl

I would like to repeat the following commands if the file `$grib` doesn't exist, till it exists.. What is the best way to introduce a loop in order to repeatedly check whether the file exists.

```
$grib = "model.grb";

if ( -e $grib ) {
    print "File $grib exists";
}
else {
    print "without file $grib";
}
```

Comment: With a `while` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `while` loop.

```
while (!-e $grin) {
    # do stuff...
}

print "file $grib exists\n";
```

See [compound statements in perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements).

Comment: Except that you really shouldn't do this as you'll be thrashing the CPU as hard as it will go just to repeat the check every few microseconds. A `sleep 1` in there would be a huge improvement.

Comment: See also [Filesys::Notify::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::Notify::Simple).